# XML schema validation issue with JAXB

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I made an XSD and have a XML schema to validate with JAXB. Validation fails. I don't understand and I don't known how to fix this. Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd"
    targetNamespace="http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd"> 
    
    <xs:complexType name="menuType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="titre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="lien" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="menus" type="tns:menusType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   


    <xs:complexType name="menusType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="menu" type="tns:menuType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="menus" type="tns:menusType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xs:menus 
    xmlns:xs="http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xs:menu>
        <xs:titre>Accueil</xs:titre>
        <xs:lien>accueil</xs:lien>
    </xs:menu>
    <xs:menu>
        <xs:titre>Guide des épisodes</xs:titre>
        <xs:lien>guideDesEpisodes</xs:lien>
        <xs:menus>
            <xs:menu>
                <xs:titre>Introduction</xs:titre>
                <xs:lien>introduction</xs:lien>
            </xs:menu>
            <xs:menu>
                <xs:titre>La série</xs:titre>
                <xs:lien>laSerie</xs:lien>
            </xs:menu>
        </xs:menus>
    </xs:menu>
    <xs:menu>
        <xs:titre>Forum</xs:titre>
        <xs:lien>http://le-multivers.forumpro.fr/c14-farscape</xs:lien>
    </xs:menu>
</xs:menus>
```

JAXB parsing: It fails when unmarshalling

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MenusType.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdFile);
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

return (MenusType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

Thanks you in advance

```
jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: élément inattendu (URI : "http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd", local : "menus"). Les éléments attendus sont (none) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1102) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:527) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:509) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:75) at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137) at
```

XSD and XML resource used exists. I try to validate the xml with the xsd schema but it fails. I don't know why. Shema seems to be set correctly (?)

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is valid, but the instance document is not valid against the schema. Here is what the Saxon validator has to say:

```
Validation error on line 5 column 13 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <xs:menus>: The content model does not allow element
  <xs:menu> to appear as the first child. The element is in namespace
  http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd but it should be in no namespace. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
Validation error on line 13 column 19 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <xs:menus>: The content model does not allow element
  <xs:menu> to appear as the first child. The element is in namespace
  http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd but it should be in no namespace. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
Error on line 27 column 12 of test.xml:
  XQDY0027  Two validation errors were reported. First error: In content of element
  <xs:menus>: The content model does not allow element <xs:menu> to appear as the first
  child. The element is in namespace http://localhost/universe/menu-schema.xsd but it should
  be in no namespace. 
Validation complete: errors found
```

If you want to change your schema so the instance document validates, add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the `xs:schema` element. Alternatively, if you want to change the instance document so it validates against the schema as written, change elements such as `titre` and `lien` so they are in no namespace.

Comment: Thanks you for your response.
It has been fixed by generate a xml root element annotation by changing xsd on that way (no external complex type for root element)